# Typo3 - How to include all CSS and JS Files in merged File

Tags: javascript, css, merge, typo3, seo

There are multiple js and css libaries loaded (see code snippet)

Basically, this is what I have right now:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/7a1973f505-d75d99e70d86f83941cb8dde29be02ed.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-4c85787f15040b42f80e9b8c12940eda-46385b6288d9ae801d3574a36a4f492d.css" media="all">


<script src="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/jquery-3.2.1.min-0e2a44e5d7960526ea22d19998a23651.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-62fcf9b86d5d5537cbb754d505e7050c-e3f29e58f7f84473b47512d5d903396a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is what I want to get:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-4c85787f15040b42f80e9b8c12940eda-46385b6288d9ae801d3574a36a4f492d.css" media="all">

<script src="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-62fcf9b86d5d5537cbb754d505e7050c-e3f29e58f7f84473b47512d5d903396a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Depending on where some extentions get into play, there are multiple libaries not included into the merged one.

I do know where the original libs are coming from (before getting stored in typo3temp), however I don't know how to include those into the merged files.

The typoscript setup should be correct. It is configured like this:

```
config {

concatenateJs = 1
compressJs = 1
compressCss = 1
concatenateCss = 1
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a `excludeFromConcatenation = 1` or `disableCompression = 1` somewhere in the config?

Edit:

There is also `includeJS` or `includeJSFooter` or `includeJSFooterlibs`  or `includeJSLibs` in page configuration of TypoScript are they difering maybe?

The Pagerenderer.php file is somehow seeing them as separate things to concatenate..

I checked a few Typo3 sites of our own company, they have 1 file only, 1 request. So there must be something different, with the page configuration?

This code in TypoScript:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page {
   # set properties ... (lot of configuration code)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly, this is not it.